# How to integrate AIML chat bot in Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, bots, chatbot, aiml

I have a web page where I just play with HTML, CSS and Javascript.
I have decided to create a Chat Bot there.

AIML seems like the way to go, and I already know how to write it.

Question is: After I have my bot.aiml file, what do I do with it?
I assume I need some sort of javascript function to interact with it.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have access to HTML, CSS and JavaScript and not to some server-side technology, then you will need a JavaScript AIML interpreter.

A quick search turns up the following:

[AIML Interpreter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aimlinterpreter) written in node.js

> AIMLInterpreter is a module that allows you to parse AIML files and to find the correct answer to a given message.

[aiml-high](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aiml-high) written in node.js. Built on aimlinterpreter.

> aiml-high is a module that allows you to parse AIML files and to find the correct answer to a given message.

[Surly2](https://github.com/mrchimp/surly2)

> a half-complete node.js AIML interpreter with a bad attitude.
>
> Surly2 is a remake from the ground up of Surly using Node 5 and using as much asynchronicity as possible.

[burly](https://github.com/Ovyerus/burly)

> Burly is a fork of Surly2

Comment: What if I use only HTML, CSS and JS. I want to deploy my website in github pages for hosting, what can i do to integrate aiml chatbot in my website?

Answer (score 0):

I too searched for the same but sadly i was not successful of creating my own bot..instead i found a website which will do exactly the same instead of we reinventing the cycle...

- Create your account over here 
  http://www.pandorabots.com/botmaster/en/new-account
- After signing in you have option of uploading your own AIML file and use the deafult AIML files and also Custom HTML and much more....

Answer (score 0):

[ChatterBean](http://www.geocities.ws/phelio/chatterbean/) can help you to interpret the AIML files. From [Alicebot.org](http://www.alicebot.org/downloads/programs.html),

> ChatterBean is an AIML interpreter (also known as "Alicebot") written in pure Java.

For integration with Web, host a J2EE application with ChatterBean.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have understanding of chatbot, you can integrate it to your webpage by using php or j2ee (jsp being the easiest) which would send a request to the bot methods and return response.